# How to add commands dynamically in VSPackage (Visual Studio 2013 Package)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-addins, vspackage

I developed an Addin for VS2012, it is displayed in the code window (editor's) context menu. There's a menu which has a sub-menu. Sub-menu items are added dynamically, for instance..

```
 Cut
 Copy
 Paste
   .
   .
   .
 My Menu >  sub menu item 1
            sub menu item 2
            sub menu item 3
```

Now for Visual Studio 2013 I need to convert (almost re-write) the addin as VSPackage.

I am able to create a command, but I cannot add commands dynamically as sub menu items.

Please download the source code (VSPackage for VS2013) from: http://sdrv.ms/INbIu2

Question

How can I make a menu and dynamic sub menu in VSPackage?

I would really appreciate any example.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **DynamicItemStart** flag on a command definition in your .vsct file: [How to: Dynamically Add Menu Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166492.aspx).

Also, check the respective "Walkthrough" topics.

Comment: Thanks SergeyVlasov, let me follow the guide/tutorial and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, The link was helpful. It wasn't too straightforward though, however, I managed to do it. There is only one problem, It first shows a command button, I need to press it at first before it starts to show me the menu. I am unable to handle it. (please see the image I have uploaded on the same location: http://sdrv.ms/INbIu2) Could you suggest me something please?

Comment: To show menu your package should be loaded, but VS by default don't load packages on startup (it loads them for example when you invoke a package command like your command button). Add the ProvideAutoLoad attribute for your main package class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166762.aspx

Answer (score -1):

The VSPackage you are creating can still add and remove commands via the same APIs that you used from your Add-In.

Comment: Thanks JaredPar, I know it is possible, the question is how can I do that. VSPackage implementation seems complicated yet messy. Too mnay dependencies made it difficult for me to understand the flow and dynamic behavior.

Comment: This does not appear to be true. The commands to add menu items require an Addin instance, which is not available to Extensions. All these calls are documented in MSDN as "deprecated" in VS 2013 which means that they cannot be relied on to exist in the future (and that future may already be here with VS 2015).